# How to insert data with singlequotes, doublequotes and slashes?

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, replace

I have a field (WASIS below) where I need to accept anything the user types: special characters, single quotes, double quotes, slashes, etc. In order to allow it, I am doing as follows:

```
INSERT INTO CP_WASIS(IDWASIS, IDCP, IDDeveloper, WASdef)
VALUES (
    #wasisid#
    , #id#
    , #developer#
    , '#replace(replace(replace(Wasdef, "”","""","all"),"“","""","all")," – "," - ","all")#'
 )
```

It allows the variable to have single and double quotes, but does not allow it to have slashes. I need the slashes to be accepted too.

How should I write this code to work as I need?

Comment: Please research before posting. The tag cfqueryparam should show up in Google searches for this type of issue often.

Comment: You should be using `cfqueryparam`. Not only will it handle quoting issues without the need for a bunch of replace statements, it will protect your database from sql injection.

Comment: I'm sorry Chris Tierney, but try to search in google for: coldfusion mysql slashes singlequotes doublequotes

Comment: ...or any combination of the keywords above, yes, nothing useful comes, the only way to find cfqueryparam was if I already knew this funcition. Anyway, thanks for your help, it was very useful, I classified your answer as correct and fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<cfqueryparam>
```

will solve this for you.